# Internal Error. java.lang.RunTimeException:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Android Studio does not open

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, startup

This is what i get if i load android studio.

[image]

I wanted to install the recently updated version of android studio, once i did it, the android studio itself stopped opening and it displays a message like this.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors. Since you're on Windows, do Ctrl-C to copy the error to your clipboard (it should work even if it doesn't highlight) and paste the error inside of code tags. This makes it easier to google on the specific error messages that you're getting. And if you get a good answer, having that error in text format will make it easier for others to google those same kind of error messages and find your actual question.

Comment: Just turn off Internet Connection.

Comment: off-topic: not about programming, but about running a software

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with an argument which seems to be null.

Open the folder "bin" under the directory where you installed your Android Studio. Find the file "idea.properties" and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools. Add

`disable.android.first.run=true` as the final line and save the file.

Restart Android Studio